# php complex numbering computing

Tags: php

I have an orderId which obviously is variable.

I need to compute another 9 digit number based on that.

Example:

```
$orderId = 100;

$path should be = 0000000100;

----
$orderId = 2350;

$path should be = 0000002000;


--- 
$orderId = 7500;

$path should be = 0000007000;
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: ok. And what will be 9 digit number for 7999 according to you?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Leaving that aside, I don't see a clear rule on how to build that. Do you round down if it's x.5? Do you round up if it's bigger than x.5? I can only assume you round down at this point.

Comment: First off, your examples are 10 instead of 9 digits? So, the general logic is: keep the first digit of orderId, append as many zeros at the end to keep the number of digits from the original and then fill up the front with zeros to reach 9 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
 <?php
  $test = strval(7001);
  echo substr_replace(str_pad("",9,"0"),$test[0],(strlen($test)-1)*(-1),0);
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/607614

Another way is

```
<?php
$test = 658;
$length = 10-strlen($test);
$str_pad = "0000000000";
$str_pad[$length] = strval($test)[0];
echo $final = $str_pad
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/607610

Comment: @DhavalDave : Changed `10` to `9` logic is same